# BFS using deque

Tags: c++, deque, breadth-first-search

Really having trouble figuring out how to fix my code. I know there are obviously errors since it isn't running, but I'm unsure of what exactly they are, or how to go about fixing them. Any help/insight would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!!

```
struct vertices
{
    int value;
    int parent;
    int visited;
    int distance;
};


int BFS(vertices *v, int **adj_matrix, int num_nodes)
{
    int target;
    int cur_v = 0;
    bool found = false;
    int steps = 0;
    cin >> target >> num_nodes;
    adj_matrix [num_nodes][num_nodes];
    deque<int> q;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++)
    {
        v[i].visited = 0;
        v[i].distance = INFINITY;
        v[i].parent = 0;

        v[1].visited = 1;
        v[i].distance = 0;
        q.push_front(v[1].value);

        while(!q.empty())
        {
            cur_v = q.front();
            q.pop_back();
            v[cur_v].visited = 1;
            for(int n=0; n< num_nodes; n++)
            {
                if(adj_matrix[cur_v][i] == n)
                {
                    if(v[n].visited == 0)
                    {
                        v[n].visited = 1;
                        v[n].distance = ((v[cur_v].distance)+1);
                        v[n].parent = cur_v;
                        q.push_front(v[n].value);
                        steps ++;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return steps;
}

int main()
{
    int target;
    int num_nodes;

    cin >> target;
    cin >> num_nodes;

    vertices *v = new vertices[num_nodes];

    int **adj_matrix [num_nodes][num_nodes];

    for(int i=0; i < num_nodes; ++i)
    {
        int node;
        int value;
        cin >> node >> value;

        int num_edges;
        cin >> num_edges;

        for(int j=0; j<num_edges;++j)
        {
            int other_node;
            cin >> other_node;

            **adj_matrix[node][other_node] = 1;
            **adj_matrix[other_node][node] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to cut this code down to the important parts if you can - the parts that are producing the problem and are vitally related to it.

Comment: Your matrix might be filled with garbage if you didn't zero it out.

Comment: @JamesRoot how would I fix that?? By popping out all of the values from the deque at the end?

Comment: When you create the matrix, initialize it like `int matrix[size][size]{}`. It'll initialize all the elements to `0`.

Comment: Also, variable length arrays aren't standard. You should use `vector`.

Comment: `**adj_matrix[node][other_node] = 1;` Please care to explain what this line is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious error is that you are using the wrong data
    structure. When you are implementing known concepts like matrix,
    BFS, you need to spend a good amount of time to think about how to
    implement inputs , outputs, data structures from the algorithm.

Some people like to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for matrices. I almost always uses `std::vector<int>` for matrix data.

Second  error is that you are **mutating** the algorithm. That thing is not BFS. It is not obvious at first.

- You call multiple instance of BFS inside you BFS implementation. Using the same input vertices, whose elements are being modified. At the next loop, you dont start with a clean state.
- You are **flattening** the algorithm, removing abstractions. What if you now have to use a adjency list? You have to modify the whole thing.

Third obvious error is coding style. You didnt do such a bad job because the vertices structure is self explanatory

- I had to highlight all instances of `cur_v`to realizes that it stands for ***current vertex***.
- Using `n` for a counter is not a great idea.
- Taking input inside the algorithm implementation is a big nono.